# Seeking more information regarding the "rigoidal category" of $\mathbb{N}$-graded sets

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

**Definitions.**

- By an $\mathbb{N}$-*graded set*, I mean a set $X$ together with a function $|\Box|_X:\mathbb{N} \leftarrow X,$ called the *grading.* These will simply be called *graded sets* hereafter.
- If $Y$ and $X$ are graded sets, then a function $f : Y \leftarrow X$ is said to be a *morphism of graded sets* iff it preserves the grading up to equality. Meaning that: $$\left(\mathop{\forall}_{x:X}\right)\;|f(x)|_Y = | x|_X$$

  (There's a weaker version in which we only require $\leq$ in the above condition, but we won't be using that here.)
- Write $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbb{N}$ for the category of graded sets (this is equivalent to the functor category $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbb{N}$).
- If $Y$ and $X$ are graded sets, define $Y \oplus X$ as follows.

  - Its underlying set is $Y \times X$.
  - The new grading is defined additively: $$\left(\mathop{\forall}_{y,x:X}\right)\; |(y,x)|_{Y \oplus X} = |y|_Y+|x|_X$$
- If $Y$ and $X$ are graded sets, define $Y \otimes X$ as follows.

  $$Y \otimes X = \bigsqcup_{y:Y} X^{\oplus |y|}$$
- Define a function $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbb{N} \leftarrow \mathbb{N}$ by assigning to each natural number $n$ a graded set $\underline{n}$ with precisely one element, whose grade equals $n.$

We have: $$\left(\mathop{\forall}_{a,b:\mathbb{N}}\right)\; \underline{a+b} \cong \underline{a} \oplus \underline{b}, \qquad \left(\mathop{\forall}_{a,b:\mathbb{N}}\right)\;\underline{ab} \cong \underline{a} \otimes \underline{b}$$

I haven't checked the details, but this seems to make $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbb{N}$ into a kind of categorified rig; a "rigoidal category," if you will, with identity elements $\underline{0}$ and $\underline{1}$ respectively. My main interest in this structure is to give a description of operads; it seems to be the case that an *operad* can be defined as a monoid object in the monoidal category $(\mathbf{Set}^\mathbb{N}, \otimes, \underline{1}).$ Anyway, I'd like to get more information.

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Does this description of operads work? If so, can we describe symmetric operads in a similar way? What about cartesian operads? Where can I learn more?
>
> **Q1.** Does this "rigoidal category" misbehave in any unexpected ways? Failure of distributivity, etc? Further to that, supposing that we want $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbb{N}$ to form a "rigoidal category," what are the appropriate axioms of a "rigoidal category"? Is there somewhere I can learn more about such structures?

Comment: For a definition of operads along these lines, see the section "Definition as a monoid" at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/operad.  Note that that version incorporates the usual permutation action on the $n$'th space, whereas yours does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $M$ is any monoidal category, the presheaf category $[M^{op}, \text{Set}]$ inherits a monoidal structure given by [Day convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution). It is uniquely determined by the condition that it restricts to the given monoidal structure on $M$ and that it preserves colimits in both variables. Taking $M = \mathbb{N}$ (as a discrete monoidal category) we recover the monoidal category of $\mathbb{N}$-graded sets (with the first monoidal structure you describe).

$\mathbb{N}$ is the free monoidal category on a point. Consequently, by the universal property of the Yoneda embedding, $[\mathbb{N}^{op}, \text{Set}]$ is the free monoidal cocomplete (this includes the condition that the monoidal structure distributes over colimits) category on a point. If you think of cocomplete categories as analogous to abelian groups, then monoidal cocomplete categories are analogous to rings, so this free guy is analogous to a polynomial ring.

One way to describe the universal property above is that $[\mathbb{N}^{op}, \text{Set}]$ represents the forgetful functor from monoidal cocomplete categories to categories. Accordingly, it is also equivalent to the category of natural transformations from this forgetful functor to itself. This means that $\mathbb{N}$-graded sets are "universal endomorphisms" of monoidal cocomplete categories: explicitly, if $X_n$ is an $\mathbb{N}$-graded set, the corresponding endomorphism of monoidal cocomplete categories acts on an object $V$ via the "ordinary generating function"

$$V \mapsto \coprod_n X_n \otimes V^{\otimes n}.$$

This gives $\mathbb{N}$-graded sets a new monoidal structure, the composition product (analogous to composition rather than multiplication of polynomials; this is the second monoidal structure you describe). This means that a monoid in $\mathbb{N}$-graded sets (with respect to the composition product) is a "universal monad" acting on monoidal cocomplete categories, and if you work out what that means in terms of the action above it is precisely a nonsymmetric operad.

To get symmetric operads replace "monoidal" above everywhere with "symmetric monoidal." This replaces $\mathbb{N}$ with the category $S$ of finite sets and bijections, which is the free symmetric monoidal category on a point. Consequently, the category $[S^{op}, \text{Set}]$ of [species](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/species) is the free symmetric monoidal cocomplete category on a point. It acts as "universal endomorphisms" of symmetric monoidal cocomplete categories as follows: if $X_n$ is a species, the corresponding endomorphism acts on an object $V$ via the "exponential generating function"

$$V \mapsto \coprod_n X_n \otimes_{S_n} V^{\otimes n}.$$

Again we get a composition product. This means that a monoid in species (with respect to the composition product) is a "universal monad" acting on symmetric monoidal cocomplete categories, and if you work out what that means in terms of the action above it is precisely a symmetric operad.

I haven't thought about how to get cartesian operads (these are Lawvere theories, right?) into the game, but plausibly you can do it by replacing "symmetric monoidal" with "cartesian monoidal."

Comment: @goblin: incidentally, this is not a rig category (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig+category) with the monoidal structures you describe: the composition product doesn't distribute over the usual product. You can already see that this isn't true for polynomials, where polynomial composition doesn't distribute over polynomial multiplication.

Comment: I see. I presume it distributes on one side, though?

Comment: The Lawvere theory version is the same. The free cartesian monoidal category on one object is $\mathbf{FinSet}^\mathrm{op}$, and the presheaf category $[\mathbf{FinSet}, \mathbf{Set}]$ has a composition monoidal structure in which the monoids are Lawvere theories. Equivalently, one could observe that $[\mathbf{FinSet}, \mathbf{Set}]$ is equivalent to the monoidal category of endofunctors on $\mathbf{Set}$ that preserve filtered colimits, and then go via accessible monads.

Comment: I had written some notes here which might be useful: https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/Towards+a+doctrine+of+operads

Comment: Qiaochu, you write that: "the category of finite sets and bijections is the free symmetric monoidal category on a point." What happens if we replace "symmetric monoidal category" with "symmetric monoidal category equipped with an endofunctor $X \mapsto -X$ and natural isomorphisms $X \oplus -X \cong 0, -X \oplus X \cong 0.$" Do we get a categorification of the integers?

Comment: @goblin: there are a couple of variants on that idea that seem more natural to me. One is to ask for the free symmetric monoidal category on an invertible object. This gives something which can be identified with the $1$-truncation of the sphere spectrum; in particular it has $\pi_0 \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Another is to ask for the free symmetric monoidal category on a dualizable object. This gives the 1-dimensional cobordism category (this is the 1-dimensional case of the cobordism hypothesis).